# Java - Illegal Start of Expression

Tags: java

so I did a few searches for this error and found a few results. However, none of them seem to be an answer. I'm sure the problem is simple and that I'm just too tired to figure it out, but I dunno what my mistake is. The methods are meant to be mutator methods to increase or decrease the volume.

```
Television.java:94: error: illegal start of expression
public int increaseVolume()
^
Television.java:94: error: ';' expected
public int increaseVolume()
                        ^
Television.java:103: error: illegal start of expression
public int decreaseVolume()
^
Television.java:103: error: ';' expected
 public int decreaseVolume()
                        ^
Television.java:106: error: reached end of file while parsing
}
^
5 errors
```

Here is the end of the code where the errors are occuring:

```
public class Television
{
private String MANUFACTURER = "None"; // This represents the manufacturer of the TV set.
private int SCREEN_SIZE = 0; // This represents the size of screen of the TV set.
private boolean powerOn; // This represents the state the TV is in (On or Off)
private int channel; // This represents the channel the TV set is on.
private int volume; // This represents the volume value of the TV set.

public static void main(String[] args)
  {

  }  

 /**
  Constructor
  @param brand The manufacturer brand of the TV set.
  @param size The screen size of the TV set.
 */

public Television(String brand, int size)
{
 MANUFACTURER = brand;
 SCREEN_SIZE = size;
 powerOn = false;
 volume = 20;
 channel = 2;
}

 /**
     The getVolume method gets the volume of the TV set.
     @return The current volume on the TV set as an integer.
 */
public int getVolume()
  {
     return volume;
  }

/**
  The getChannel method gets the channel of the TV set.
  @return The current channel on the TV set as an integer.
*/
  public int getChannel()
    {
      return channel;
    }

/**
  The getScreenSize method gets the screen size of the TV set.
  @return The screen size as an integer.
*/
 public int getScreenSize()
  {
    return SCREEN_SIZE;
  }

/** 
  The getManufacturer method gets the brand manufacturer of the TV set.
  @return The manufacturer name as a string.
*/
 public String getManufacturer()
  {
    return MANUFACTURER;
  }

/**
  The setChannel method is designed to set the channel for the user.
  @return The channel on the TV that is set.
*/
public int setChannel(int chan)
{
  return channel = chan;
}

/**
  The power method is designed to take the current power state and turn it on or off based on its current state.
  @return The power state after it is changed.
*/
public boolean power()
  {
 if (powerOn = true)
 {
   return powerOn = !powerOn;
 }
 else
 {
    return powerOn = false;
 }

 /**
  The increaseVolume method is designed to increase the volume of the TV set in increments of 1.
  @return The volume of the TV set as it is after being increased.
 */
 public int increaseVolume()
   {
    return volume += 1;
   }

 /**
  The decreaseVolume method is designed to decrease the volume of the TV set in increments of 1.
  @return The volume of the TV set as it is after being decreased.
 */
 public int decreaseVolume()
   {
    return volume -= 1;
   }
  }
}
```

I'm either really tired or an idiot. Sorry if it's so obvious.

Comment: Have u copy the source code from somewhere?

Comment: It is either outside a calss, or inside another method.

Comment: It's just a guess - braces mismatch

Comment: Watch the code above `public int increaseVolume().`  You might have missed a `;` or `}.` If you cant find the problem, post the full code.

Comment: post the complete code.. it seems to me that you have given one extra braces in the end of the class

Comment: Found it. Inside the if statement I had forgotten a brace. I knew it would be something stupid like that.

Comment: @WillBro good you got it

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to close the method `power()` and remove one  `}` at the end of the class

Adding to that, you need to change this `if (powerOn = true)` to `if (powerOn == true)`. You are assigning the value to `powerOn` instead of testing equality

Answer (score 0):

you have missing one close braces at `public boolean power()` method

```
  public class Television
    {
    private String MANUFACTURER = "None"; // This represents the manufacturer of the TV set.
    private int SCREEN_SIZE = 0; // This represents the size of screen of the TV set.
    private boolean powerOn; // This represents the state the TV is in (On or Off)
    private int channel; // This represents the channel the TV set is on.
    private int volume; // This represents the volume value of the TV set.

    public static void main(String[] args)
      {

      }  

     /**
      Constructor
      @param brand The manufacturer brand of the TV set.
      @param size The screen size of the TV set.
     */

    public Television(String brand, int size)
    {
     MANUFACTURER = brand;
     SCREEN_SIZE = size;
     powerOn = false;
     volume = 20;
     channel = 2;
    }

     /**
         The getVolume method gets the volume of the TV set.
         @return The current volume on the TV set as an integer.
     */
    public int getVolume()
      {
         return volume;
      }

    /**
      The getChannel method gets the channel of the TV set.
      @return The current channel on the TV set as an integer.
    */
      public int getChannel()
        {
          return channel;
        }

    /**
      The getScreenSize method gets the screen size of the TV set.
      @return The screen size as an integer.
    */
     public int getScreenSize()
      {
        return SCREEN_SIZE;
      }

    /** 
      The getManufacturer method gets the brand manufacturer of the TV set.
      @return The manufacturer name as a string.
    */
     public String getManufacturer()
      {
        return MANUFACTURER;
      }

    /**
      The setChannel method is designed to set the channel for the user.
      @return The channel on the TV that is set.
    */
    public int setChannel(int chan)
    {
      return channel = chan;
    }

    /**
      The power method is designed to take the current power state and turn it on or off based on its current state.
      @return The power state after it is changed.
    */
    public boolean power()
      {
     if (powerOn == true)
     {
       return powerOn = !powerOn;
     }
     else
     {
        return powerOn = false;
     }
    }////here is missing breces
     /**
      The increaseVolume method is designed to increase the volume of the TV set in increments of 1.
      @return The volume of the TV set as it is after being increased.
     */
     public int increaseVolume()
       {
        return volume += 1;
       }

     /**
      The decreaseVolume method is designed to decrease the volume of the TV set in increments of 1.
      @return The volume of the TV set as it is after being decreased.
     */
     public int decreaseVolume()
       {
        return volume -= 1;
       }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You miss a `}` in here:

```
public boolean power()
{
if (powerOn = true)
{
return powerOn = !powerOn;
}
else
{
return powerOn = false;
}
//
//Here is } missing
//

/**
 The increaseVolume method is designed to increase the volume of the TV set in increments of 1.
@return The volume of the TV set as it is after being increased.
*/
public int increaseVolume()
{
return volume += 1;
}
```

Anyway, if you have errors in compile time I recomend you to use an IDE to check the sintax errors if you stock again with these kind of errors